# Checking condition on matrix/array element-wise modulo an integer

Tags: python, numpy, math, matrix, julia

My aim is to check whether a matrix (i.e. a 2D array) modulo d is Symplectic (see condition on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix). That is, whether there is any Symplectic matrix in the set of matrices that are element-wise equal modulo some number d.

Is there any logical and especially efficient way to check such a condition involving matrixmultiplication without the need to loop through (possible) infinite matrices?
The target language is Julia, however, if anyone has a python solution that's fine as well. The condition without modulo d condition in Julia is now implemented this way (with tolerance 0.001 and M an 2n x 2n array):

```
omega = [zeros((n,n)) Matrix(1I, n, n)); -Matrix(1I, n, n) zeros((n,n))]

isSymplec = maximum(abs.(transpose(M)*(omega*M) - omega)) < 0.001
```

Just as an simple example: The array/matrix [1 0 0 0; 1 1 0 0; 0 0 1 1; 0 0 0 1] is *not* symplectic but has a modulo 2 symplectic "equivalent" partner: [1 0 0 0; 1 1 0 0; 0 0 1 -1; 0 0 0 1]

Comment: So you need to know if at least one of such matrices exists ? Because for your example there is an infinite number of possible solution, we see that each matrices `[1 0 0 0; n 1 0 0; 0 0 1 -n; 0 0 0 1]` where `n` is a positive integer will be a solution.

Comment: I think this is a pretty-hard math problem rather than a programming one and so it should be a good idea to ask the question on https://math.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @obchardon I agree for that case, but for sure that's not the case for any input. This just one of the simple cases. But yes, indeed, it's not the exercise to actually find the explicit solution but whether there is any. That's why I understand, but would disagree with ,Jerome Richard  that this is a math problem since the condition that is to be statisfied is clear. It's about how to tell the computer to answer the yes/no question based upon this condition. What makes it hard is the fact that matrix-multiplication is involved.

Comment: Even if the condition that is to be satisfied is clear, you potentially need to check an infinite number of possible matrices. So you need a mathematical trick, if there is any, in order to reduce the number of computations needed. I agree with @JérômeRichard, this question is more suited for [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks, guys, I'll try it over there and close this question soon.

Comment: For completeness: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4136226/check-whether-a-matrix-is-symplectic-modulo-integer-d

Comment: But sadly, the question at math.sx has been deleted, leaving only this site as the way to answer this question.